# How do I install opencv-python on pypy3 windows?

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I'm kind of new in the programming world, and I've heard that pypy3 is 7x faster than python while running code, so I decided to give it a try. I created a bot to farm EXP on the game Yu-Gi-OH! duel links and wanted to run it with pypy3, however I need to install opencv and every time I try to do so I get this error .

commands I ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python
cd opencv-python
pypy3 setup.py install
```

Error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 457, in <module>
     main()
   File "setup.py", line 257, in main
     cmake_source_dir=cmake_source_dir,
   File "C:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\pypy3.6-v7.3.3-win32\site packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 625, in setup
     cmake_source_dir, skbuild_kw['cmake_install_dir'])
   File "setup.py", line 370, in _classify_installed_files_override
      raise Exception("Not found: '%s'" % relpath_re)
 Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2[^/]*\.pyd'
```

obs: I'm using windows

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try `pypy3 -m pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: yes i did, it didn't work as well.